# Images being stretched in WPF RibbonRadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf

I've already posted a message about this, but I've lost it! And I can paste code now too...

I have a RibbonRadioButton whose image is being stretched, XAML below (I haven't changed the code-behind from its default). I have checked that the PNG is at 96dpi but the problem remains.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DashboardTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="LiveStatusGroup"
                                    Header="RibbonGroup Header">
                <ribbon:RibbonRadioButton x:Name="Dashboard"
                                              LargeImageSource="images\LiveStatus_Dashboard.png"
                                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Label="RibbonRadioButton Label"
                                              ToolTip="RibbonRadioButton ToolTip"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
        </ribbon:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening? I am running Windows 7 with text size set to medium (125%).

J

Comment: can you set the stretch property to none ...

Comment: Try `SmallImageSource`.

Comment: stretch property? Where's that?

Comment: SmallImageSource results in no image at all!

Comment: Please check these MSDN links.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonradiobutton.smallimagesource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx    and     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonimagesize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I've placed the image side-by-side next to my ribbon button to check. It looks as though instead of being stretched, the image anti-aliasing isn't working propertly. I shall investigate.

Comment: Nope can't work it out! Can anyone tell me how to fix the antialiasing on a RibbonRadioButton image please?

Comment: Those MSDN links weren't really helpful unfortunately. I know about smallimage/largeimage and have tried both.